# Iterating string elements in a list and appending a portion of that string into an empty list

Tags: python, string, list

In the code below there is a transaction list containing the name , price  , color and the date of a transaction . I want to append the names say 'John', 'Jay' in the customers list , the price say $1.21 ,$2.12 in sales list and the color say 'white', 'red' in the color list. 
Iterating the list would just give the elements within the ' ' (quotes). How do i append the names , price , color specifically into these empty lists ?:

```
    transaction = ['John:$1.21:white:09/15/17','Jay:$2.12:red:09/15/17','Leo:$3,5:blue:09/15/17']
    customers = [names_of_customer]
    sales = [price_of_goods]
    color = [color_of_goods]
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you are stuck with solving this yourself? Do you know how to split a string on a specific delimiter into parts? Do you know how to append new elements to another list? Each of those actions are basic actions that you probably already know how to do, where you don't want us explaining to you what you already know.

Comment: Just having trouble on how do i append this say only name specifically into the customers list or only the color in the color list .When I am appending the entire thing 'John:$1.21:white:09/15/17' is getting appended .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet which uses the **split** method to achieve the required output.

```
transaction = ['John:$1.21:white:09/15/17','Jay:$2.12:red:09/15/17','Leo:$3,5:blue:09/15/17']
customers=[]
sales=[]
color=[]
for tran in transaction:
    elems = tran.split(':')
    customers.append(elems[0])
    sales.append(elems[1]) 
    color.append(elems[2])

print customers
print sales
print color
```